# Ruby: filter array removing blacklisted names

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Say I have an array of sentences:

```
sentences = ["Tom is a good person", "Jack spent some time", "Kat did something wrong"]
```

and I have a blacklist of names:

```
blacklist = ["Jack", "Kat"]
```

Now I need to filter `sentences` into an array that removes all the sentences that contain blacklisted names, so:

```
["Tom is a good person"]
```

How would I do it in Ruby?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sentences = ["Tom is a good person", "Jack spent some time", "Kat did something wrong",
             "Kathy knows her stuff"]

blacklist = ["Jack", "Kat"]
```

```
r = /\b#{Regexp.union(blacklist)}\b/
  #=> /\b(?-mix:Jack|Kat)\b/
sentences.reject { |s| s.match?(r) }
  #=> ["Tom is a good person", "Kathy knows her stuff"]
```

Word breaks (`\b`) are needed in the regular expression so that `"Kat"` does not match the first three letters of `"Kathy"`. One could instead write:

```
r = /\b#{blacklist.join('|')}\b/
  #=> /\bJack|Kat\b/
```

Comment: Thanks let me try.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reject the records

```
sentences.reject!{|sentence| sentence.match(blacklist.join('|'))}
```

You will get the required output -

```
["Tom is a good person"]
```

Docs for reject! - https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21

`reject!` will update the same array, if you don't want that, you can use `reject` and store in a new array.

Go back to `=~` :)

```
sentences.reject!{|sentence| !((Regexp.new(blacklist.join('|')) =~ sentence).nil?) }
```

Reject the sentence, if `=~' finds a match ( Code used - !nil? )

This is going to do essentially the same thing. Although ruby says, match is faster

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but it complains `match` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentences = ["Tom is a good person", "Jack spent some time", "Kat did something wrong"]

blacklist = ["Jack", "Kat"]
```

Program

```
p sentences.filter{|string|!(blacklist.map{|x|string.match?(x)}.any?)}
```

If you are using < Ruby 2.6 then

```
p sentences.select{|string|!(blacklist.map{|x|string.include?(x)}.any?)}
```

Result

```
["Tom is a good person"]
```

Comment: Sorry I might be using an old version of ruby (2.3.7) and I got: `undefined method `filter' for #<Array:0x00007f9bf4e796f8>`

Comment: @hzxu Okay, Now updated another method for you which works for you.

Comment: I have to change `filter` to `select` and change `match` to `include`.

Comment: @hzxu Perfectly okay then.